# Breaking a game model into parts?

Tags: select

I’m trying to figure out the best way to structure a 3D model of a playable character in Blender (and made for Unity).

For example, I have a feeling that I should separate the clothing, eyes, and hair from the body. Not separate as in pull apart, but separate as in identify/classify certain areas of the model. I don’t know how to do this but it seems useful.
Saving a selection is one thing, but I was thinking more along the lines of each part being a different object (but still it’s all one model) if that makes sense? I just want to be able to select parts quickly and be able to pull them off while editing and then be able to put them back when I’m done.

I have more questions.

Do these classified areas of a model register in Unity as well so that I can select them independently there?
My model is a human, so what are some general locations on the model that should be able to be selected independently? I plan to have textures for the mouth and eyebrows, but the eyes will be 3D.
Lastly, is there a name for this process?

I appreciate any help.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 2):

### Yes, it's possible.

Sometimes models are created with the clothing, eyes, hair, etc. as separate objects. All of these objects can be parented to the same *rig* so that they are controlled as one object.

As to which objects should be separate, it's up to you. It will depend on your reason for separating.

You could keep accessories like armor, hair, or gloves separate for interchangeability.

I'm not sure if there's a name for this. If there is, I've never heard it.

Comment: Thank you! I was wary about separating each part into their own objects because I didn’t know if this issue was context-specific, but if it’s as simple as that then it’s wonderful. I appreciate it!

Comment: Glad I could help! If my answer solved your problem, make sure you accept it (checkmark near the top) so everybody knows your question is answered.